# Pandas 2.2: FutureWarning: Resampling with a PeriodIndex is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

The pandas version 2.2 raises a warning when using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"something": {pd.Period("2022", "Y-DEC"): 2.5}})
# FutureWarning: Resampling with a PeriodIndex is deprecated.
# Cast index to DatetimeIndex before resampling instead.
print(df.resample("M").ffill())

#          something
# 2022-01        2.5
# 2022-02        2.5
# 2022-03        2.5
# 2022-04        2.5
# 2022-05        2.5
# 2022-06        2.5
# 2022-07        2.5
# 2022-08        2.5
# 2022-09        2.5
# 2022-10        2.5
# 2022-11        2.5
# 2022-12        2.5
```

This does not work:

```
df.index = df.index.to_timestamp()
print(df.resample("M").ffill())

#             something
# 2022-01-31        2.5
```

I have PeriodIndex all over the place and I need to resample them a lot, filling gaps with ffill.
How to do this with Pandas 2.2?

Comment: What version were you using before? `pd.Period("2022", "Y-DEC")` doesn't work in Pandas 2.0.3, it says `ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y-DEC`.

Comment: The old value is "A-DEC". This also changed with pandas 2.2 https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-period-aliases

Comment: FWIW, you might want to ask the maintainers directly on GitHub. Part of the reason I say that is the FutureWarning doesn't seem to cover this use-case, so they might want to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to this directly with pandas 2.2.0+.

```py
df.index = df.index.to_timestamp()
print(df.resample("M").ffill())

#             something
# 2022-01-31        2.5
```

does work but when you use `to_timestamp()` you get a single DateTime (2022-01-31) so a monthly resampling does nothing here.

You have to create a range of DateTimes first, ideally via the [date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) function. Then you can resample.

Is there a reason why you want to use pandas 2.2.0+ ?

Comment: Creating the index via a date_range adds probably a lot of code to substitute a one-liner, especially if the resampling frequency is not trivial, I still hope there might be an easier solution, but I'll see what I can achieve with the date_range. And for the other question: I don't want to use it, I have to.